# Can I chain multiple ternary shorthand operators in PHP?

Tags: php

The ternary shorthand (elvis) operator checks if the first value is truthy. If it is, PHP evaluates the expression to that first value. If not, the result is the second value.

```php
$falseyValue ?: 'expected'; //expected
```

But I've been using the null coalescing operator, and in some cases it is useful to chain it like so:

```php
$nullValue ?? $anotherNullValue ?? 'expected'; //expected
```

That checks if `$nullValue` exists and is not null. If not, check if `$anotherNullValue` exists and is not null. If not, evaluate to 'expected'.

Can the ternary shorthand operator be used in that manner?

```php
$falseyValue ?: $anotherFalseyValue ?: 'expected'; //expected
```

Comment: Why don't you start by testing it out instead of asking "can I do this...?"? If you get any issues/errors you don't understand, we can help from there (but then you need to explicitly ask about those).

Comment: Or reading a [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), __example 5__

Comment: @DavidThomas In cases where it's as simple as choosing between variables or short expressions, I find a chain of `??` or `?:` operators considerably _more_ readable than most alternatives. Similar to SQL's variadic COALESCE function `COALESCE(BestOption, SecondOption, ThirdOption)`.

Comment: @IMSoP, sure; but it's dependant on the code that's being written - and I could have been more clear about that - in most situations if a ternary is perfectly readable, but "most" isn't - as you imply with "in cases where..." - universal. Whereas I do feel that the advice to consider readability and understanding applies to most, if maybe not all, code that's written and not just ternary operators.

Comment: Nested ternaries quickly become unreadable. But chains of null-coalescing or shortcut ternaries are usually fine as long as the expressions are simple. @DavidThomas

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the ternary shorthand (elvis) operator can be chained with itself in PHP.

```php
print(false ?: false ?: "expected"); //expected
print("\n");
print(false ?: "expected" ?: false); //expected
print("\n");
print("expected" ?: false ?: false); //expected
print("\n");
print(false ?: "expected" ?: "wrong"); //expected
```

OnlinePHP sandbox:
https://onlinephp.io/c/7ced9

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can chain multiple ternary shorthand operators in PHP. The shorthand ternary operator is a shorthand way of writing a ternary expression. It's written as expr1 ?: expr3 which is equivalent to expr1 ? expr1 : expr3.

Here's an example of chaining multiple ternary shorthand operators:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
$result = $a ?: $b ?: $c;
```

In this example, if $a is truthy, $result will be set to $a, otherwise, it will check $b, if $b is truthy, $result will be set to $b, otherwise, $result will be set to $c.